# How to check minimum thai words on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with detecting minimum words using jquery.validation.js. As i got a script for uses this on english:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('minWords', function(value, element, params) {
   return !$(element).val() || $(element).val().match(/\b\w+\b/g).length >= params;
}, 'Please enter at least {0} words.');
```

This script **NOT WORK** on thai specific language. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

---

It's work now. Thanks All

Comment: Could you explain how this does not work for Thai - I assume it's becuase not all words are separated by spaces as with English?

Comment: Also, whenever asking a "how do I validate X" question, it's best to include examples of what should pass the validation, and what should fail. Which would also have helped with Rory's question.

Comment: The form return true (submitted the data) although the thai words not meet the minimum requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I counted the thai language without XRegxp, I'm modifying minWords plugin using the same method from jquery.wordcount.js. Here's the complete modified script:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('minWords', function(value, element, params) {
    return !$(element).val() || $(element).val().split(/[\s\.\?]+/).length >= params;
}, 'Please enter at least {0} words.');
```

Here's the regular expression:

```
split(/[\s\.\?]+/)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because Thai characters are Unicode characters. 
Sadly, Javascript has no built in Unicode regex functionality but there is a great plugin that does the trick:

**[XRegExp - The one of a kind JavaScript regular expression library](http://xregexp.com/plugins/)**

Check out the documentation for the usage of XRegExp.

Comment: *"It's not working because Thai characters are Unicode characters."* So is the letter "a". *"Sadly, Javascript has no built in Unicode regex functionality..."* Sure it does. What it doesn't have is the Unicode *categories* and such. But there's no problem using ranges, Unicode literals, etc.

Comment: Yes you can. You need to use the XRegExp javascript plugin.

Comment: I can detect the thai language, so how we can apply the count number using it? Thanks

Comment: Please update your main question with the changes you have made so far in your js file.